# How to use variables of strings in the access system call in c?

Tags: c

I try to check if a certain executable command exists on my system by using the access system call in c. Below you can see my code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strconcat(const char *str1, const char *str2){
    char *result = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
    strcpy(result, str1);
    strcat(result, str2);
    return result;
}

void print_error(){
    char error_message[30] = "An error has occurred\n";
    write(STDERR_FILENO, error_message, strlen(error_message));

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *shell_path = "/bin/";
    char *shell_path2 = "/usr/bin/";
    if(argc == 2){
        //batch mode
        printf("batch mode\n");

    }
    while(1){
        
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        printf("wish> ");
        getline(&line, &len, stdin);
        
        char *command_path = strconcat(shell_path, line);
        char *command_path2 = strconcat(shell_path2, line);
            
        printf("%s\n", command_path);
        printf("%s\n", command_path2);
        if(access(command_path, X_OK) == -1 && access(command_path2, X_OK) == -1){
            print_error();

        }else printf("success\n");
    }

}
```

When I give the program for example as input ls, the printed strings look like /bin/ls and /usr/bin/ls. however the access system call returns -1 in both cases. When however I replace the variables command_path and command_path2 in the access system call by the string "/bin/ls" it returns with succes. Can anyone see the problem here ?

Comment: `line` probably includes a trailing newline, which you need to remove.  Check for it.

Comment: `"An error has occurred\n"` is not a very useful message. Why don't you check errno?

Comment: thanks, a traling newline was indeed the problem!